# Getting `Page not found` error after deploying Netlify app

Tags: node.js, netlify

So here's the problem: I just deployed a Node.js survey creator to Netlify called `Formdata`. I created a Git repository and pushed it to Github, then connected it to Netlify before publishing. However, when I hit the link `formdata.netlify.app` I get a 404 error.

My server is setup to listen at port 3000:

```js
server.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', /*unnecessary console log function*/);
```

Here's what I've tried:

1. Changing the hostname for my server from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0.
2. Experimenting with different base directories.

I am new to Netlify so might not be aware of all the features that are needed.

UPDATE: The frontend now works but I am still unable to make API calls to my backend. Why might this be?

Comment: Could you post your server config and netlify config?

Comment: I reset all directories and not sure what you mean by "server config". I'm new to Netlify so...

Comment: Do you have a backend? I mean if you have a server setup with Express or something else

Comment: Yes but not with Express - just pure Node.js

Comment: How do you have that setup to serve your pages?

Comment: Or is it just one page? Really need some more info to go on

Comment: Posting that now